# D3: refactoring data source from .tsv to locally stored array

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have the following D3 configuration, which reads-in data from an external .tsv file:

```
d3.tsv("path/data.tsv", type, function(error, data) {
    if (error) throw error;

    x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.label; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.count; })]);

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .call(xAxis)
        .text("x-axis label");

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis)
        .append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text("y-axis label");

    svg.selectAll(".bar")
        .data(graphData)
        .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("class", "bar")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.label); })
        .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.count); })
        .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.count); });
});
```

I want to instead load data from a locally stored array, which takes the form

```
var graphData = [
    {label: '0', count: 0},
    {label: '0', count: 0}
];
```

I'm having a lot of trouble refactoring this. In particular, I don't know how to maintain everything in the d3.tsv callback. With .tsv, everything has to wait for the data to download, but I just need this stored variable to be my data now. I thought I could just do a d3.data function, but evidentally not. I also looked into using d3.json, but I need to access the data internally, not by pulling in a separate .json file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just drop the `d3.tsv()` part and use the callback code directly.
Your `graphData` should replace the `data` parameter of the callback, but the rest should work unchanged.

```
var graphData = [
    {label: '0', count: 0},
    {label: '0', count: 0}
];

x.domain(graphData.map(function(d) { return d.label; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(graphData, function(d) { return d.count; })]);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .call(xAxis)
    .text("x-axis label");

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("y-axis label");

svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(graphData)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.label); })
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.count); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.count); });
```